# Log4j output full class name and package

Tags: java, logging, log4j, slf4j

In a project, I'm using slf4j with log4j as the underlying logging library.
I want my log events to have the package and class name where the event was registered. Something trivial like: com.project.MyClass.

I know that, normally, I can use the %c or %C conversion characters to achieve this, but in this specific situation I can't. My log events must show some fixed number of values in a specific format. I didn't wanted to write that specific format in each call I would do to the logger, so I've created a wrapper class that contains the Logger as a static variable. In this wrapper class I've created the necessary methods to log in the adequate format, like info, debug and error. Here is a sample of the code:

```
    public final class AppLog {
        private static final Logger APP_LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger("ApplicationLogger");

        public static void info(String... args) {
            AppLog.APP_LOGGER.info(LogsUtils.generateLogString(args));
        }
        ...
    }
```

The problem is that, when using the %c or %C conversion characters, they always output the com.project.WrapperClass as the classes that logged the event. Considering the code above:
My AppLog class is in the Utils package. My log events always print Utils.AppLog as the package and class where the log was registered, but I wanted it to print the class name that called my AppLog class. It always prints:

```
2014-04-04|10:57:16,057|ERROR|utils.AppLog
2014-04-04|10:57:16,060|ERROR|utils.AppLog
2014-04-04|11:11:04,708|INFO |utils.AppLog
```

and I wanted this

```
2014-04-04|10:57:16,057|ERROR|com.project.domain.Person
2014-04-04|10:57:16,060|ERROR|com.project.dao.PersonDAO
2014-04-04|11:11:04,708|INFO |com.service.PersonService
```

One solution to fix this is injecting the class.getName() in each call to the info method in my wrapper class. But this seems like a very dirty solution for me. Is there any other solution to solve my problem that I'm not seeing?

Log4j configuration:

```
log4j.appender.APPLICATION=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.APPLICATION.file=${log.path}application.log
...
log4j.logger.ApplicationLogger=DEBUG, APPLICATION  
log4j.additivity.ApplicationLogger=false
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED ANSWER :**

Sorry I didn't get the question right. My previous answer was completly wrong;

So your problem here is that you are instanciating the logger (with `LoggerFactory`) with always the same name `ApplicationLogger`.
There is no way from this logger to find the calling class of the `AppLog` object because there is not reference to it. As you say, you can inject the logger name in each call but it will be hard to maintain.

What you can try is wrapping the `Logger` class.

```
public final class AppLogger {

    private Logger logger;       

    protected AppLogger(String  loggerName) {
         this.logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(loggerName);
    }

    public static AppLogger getAppLogger(String loggerName) {
         return new AppLogger(loggerName);
    }

    public void info(String... args) {
        this.logger.info(LogsUtils.generateLogString(args));
    }
    ...
}
```

In each class, do not use the `LoggerFactory` but your own class.

```
private static final AppLogger APP_LOGGER = AppLogger.getLogger(CallingClass.class)
```

and then log like this

```
APP_LOGGER.info("message");
```

Then in your pattern layout use %c (and not %C) and it should work as expected !

Comment: That doesn't solve my problem. That only limits, from right to left, the components to ouput in the package value. My problem is that I always get Utils.AppLog and I want to get com.project.domain.Class1, com.project.dao.PersonDao, etc...

Comment: i've updated my answer because it didn't get the question first time

Comment: Yes I think that will do the trick. But there is a small downside. I'm instanciating the logger always with the same name, "ApplicationLogger" because this is a specific Logger that I've defined in log4j.properties to log to a separated file. If I pass a CallingClass.class to the logger, it won't log to the file I want right? I'll update the main post with information about log4j config.

Comment: If you can not change the name of the logger (%c) neither the name of the class (%C) because you want to have a single class logging there is now ay to do what you want to. Why not calling your LogUtils in all classes that are using a logger ?

Comment: I'll go with your solution. Just with a small change. I'll pass the class to my logger that will still remain to be instantiated by the "ApplicationLogger" parameter. this way I have the invoker class inside my log wrapper and I can set the caller class full name. I can't change the name of the logger because I have multiple log files. And each of them can't show information from the others...